# Additional WLAN Router: enabling/disabling DHCP and WAN or LAN Port?

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I have a main router at home and the internet provider has disabled wlan from this router (I can activate it for an monthly fee, but I dont want to pay for that). I have bought a TP Link Router N that I want to connect to my main router to provide wlan. I set the IP adress of the TP Link Router to `192.168.55.1` to avoid DNS conflicts.

**My question is:**

Should I enable DHCP server on the TP Link Router and should I plug the connection cable between the routers in the WAN or LAN port of my TP Link Router? The other end is in the LAN port of my main router.

When I activate DHCP on my TP Link router and allow him to give ips in the range of `192.168.55.100` to `192.168.55.199` and put the cable in the WAN port then I can connect with my other devices to the WLAN TP Link Router and use internet. My devices get an ip in this range.

I also figured that everything still works if I disable DHCP on my TP Link Router and plug the cable in the LAN port. I found this recommendation [here](http://www.tp-link.de/faq-417.html).

My question is, which of these aproaches is correct, or what exactly is the difference? Does one of them perform better?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been simpler to just buy a Wireless Access Point?

Comment: @joeqwerty well as far as I understand it, the option to disable DHCP and using the LAN port makes the TP Link an access point. The title of the link is also **How to Configure TP-Link N router as a wireless Access Point?**. So yes, using it as an  access point works and is simple, but I would like to understand the difference between both solutions.

Comment: @joeqwerty “Real” access points are much more expensive than some random cheap router.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need to do is plug your into one of the ISP's router's LAN ports.  Then plug any additional ethernet cables into your router.  You shouldnt have to change a thing on either router.  Your router will get its WAN address from the ISP's router and all your internal IPs will come from yours.

Answer (score 0):

You plug your routers WAN port to any of the ISP router LAN ports. You can plug other devices into either routers LAN ports and they will get internet connectivity but for all your devices to see each other (a printer for example) they have to be on the same one, preferably yours.